# Accurately Incrementing and Assigning Order Numbers (eCommerce) with React.js & Firebse

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, e-commerce

I have been building a simple online store using React.js (framework) and Firebase (Hosting, Firestore, Functions, and Distributed Counter extension). I am struggling with the simple ecommerce feature to increment and assign a unique order # to each new order placed. I thought I fixed an issue where if 2+ orders are placed too quickly in succession, the backend will read the current order # then set the new order # for this order, but since two orders were placed so close together, the order # given to each order is the same. The distributed counter seems to still be working, as it is always summing the 'placed' counter properly. I found recently that this issue still existed when I quickly placed two orders in two web browser windows on my local machine.

Has anyone successfully used the Firebase Distributed Counter extension to increment then assign order numbers to orders? My setup is a bit different that the example they use which is for "visits" to "pages", mainly just on "placed" counter not being on every "order" just on my "stats" order doc.

Is it impossible to remove that slight delay of reading? I feel there has to be a work around! I was thinking maybe incrementing each order by 10 instead and adding a random number between 0-10 to that, so if there were duplicates, its a low chance they both get randomized to the same sub number (i.e. order #44 and order #48), but this feels like a janky fix, as there is still a chance they are the same.

**Related**: I am currently getting this error with the Counter Extension on the backend and am working with GCP on fixing, but my guess is it's an issue with their end: https://issuetracker.google.com/194948300

**distributed_counter.js:**
[Node.js Admin Firebase sample I used](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-counter/clients/node/index.js)

**firebase.rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Orders collection
    match /orders/{orderId} {
        function isAdmin() {
            return (
                get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/readOnly/flags).data.isAdmin == true 
            )
        }

        allow create: if true;
        allow update, read, list, delete: if isAdmin();

        // Allow to increment only the 'placed' field and only by 1.
        match /_counter_shards_/{shardId} {
            allow get;
            allow write: if request.resource.data.keys() == ["placed"]
                        && (resource == null || request.resource.data.placed ==
                        resource.data.placed + 1);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

**FFunctions index.ts:**

```
"use strict";
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
import { DocumentSnapshot } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import { CHECK_STATUSES, genId, RESPONSE_TYPES, UPLOAD_TYPES } from './common';


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const request = require("request");
const Counter = require("./distributed_counter")
const Papa = require('papaparse');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid_api.key)
...
export const onOrderCreated = functions.firestore.document('orders/{orderId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap: DocumentSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext) => {
        console.log("Order created with ID: " + context.params.orderId);
        const newValue = snap.data();

        if (newValue === null || newValue === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            const allPromises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];
            // Need to grab the shop public data for email info mainly
            let shopData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | any = null;
            await admin.firestore().collection('public').doc("shop").get().then((shopDoc) => {
                if (shopDoc.exists) {
                    const docWithMore = Object.assign({}, shopDoc.data());
                    docWithMore.id = shopDoc.id;
                    shopData = docWithMore;
                } else {
                    console.error("Shop doc doesn't exist!")
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error getting shop document:", error);
            })   

            // First test to make sure the adminViolation passes!
            if(context.params.orderId !== 'stats'){
                // Increment orderNum
                const statsRef = admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc("stats");
                let orderNum = -1;

                const orderCounter = new Counter(statsRef, "placed")
                await orderCounter.incrementBy(1);
                
                orderNum = await orderCounter.get();

                console.log("This orderNum is #" + orderNum)
                // Set stats doc with current orderNum
                allPromises.push(
                    statsRef.set({
                        lastOrdered: Date.now()
                    }, {merge: true}).then(() => {
                        console.log("Set order stats doc lastOrdered date.")
                    })
                );
                    
                // Set order number on order doc
                allPromises.push(
                    admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc(context.params.orderId).update({
                        number: orderNum
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Set processed flag to true and orderNum on order doc.")
                    })
                );    

                // Send email to user to confirm we received
                // Template email
                const htmlEmail = 
                `
                <div style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                    email sent here...
                </div>
                `

                // Pack It
                const msg = {
                    to: newValue.user.email,
                    from: `noreply@webapp.shop`,
                    subject: `${shopData?.name} Order #${orderNum}`,
                    text: `We received your order #${orderNum} successfully for ${shopData?.name}.`,
                    html: htmlEmail,
                }

                // Send it
                allPromises.push(
                    sgMail.send(msg)
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log('Order email sent')
                        })
                        .catch((error: any) => {
                            console.error(error)
                        })
                )
                    
                // Set processed flag to true when finished 
                allPromises.push(
                    admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc(context.params.orderId).update({
                        processed: true
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("Set processed flag to true and orderNum on order doc.")
                    })
                );    
            } else {
                console.log("Stats doc was created OR adminViolation flagged!!")
            }

            return Promise.all(allPromises)
        } catch(error) {
            console.error("Error: " + error);
            return;
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi OP. Let us know if the answer helped. If it's useful, consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, then accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found to this issue was to take an approach similar to Amazon, using a hashed out order # that should be unique enough down to the timeframe. I figured that theoretically, the collisions are too likely to happen with a high volume store to just increment them by 1. I found a handy library so I didn't have to re-invent the wheel here, check out the [order-id Github page](https://github.com/mderazon/order-id).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with counters is the limit mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters#web_1):

> In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic applications.

also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document):

> You should not update a single document more than once per second. If you update a document too quickly, then your application will experience contention, including higher latency, timeouts, and other errors.

For best practices, please see [**Cloud Functions best practices**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#cloud_functions).

On this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters), it explains how you can workaround this limitation using distributed counters.
Here's an example:

```
    function getCount(ref) {
        // Sum the count of each shard in the subcollection
        return ref.collection('shards').get().then((snapshot) => {
            let total_count = 0;
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                total_count += doc.data().count;
            });
    
            return total_count;
        });
    }
```

The documentation also mentions the other limitations of using the workaround.

> - **Shard count** - The number of shards controls the performance of the
>   distributed counter. With too few shards, some transactions may have
>   to retry before succeeding, which will slow writes. With too many
>   shards, reads become slower and more expensive. You can offset the
>   read-expense by keeping the counter total in a separate roll-up
>   document which is updated at a slower cadence (e.g. once per second),
>   and having clients read from that document to get the total. The
>   tradeoff is that clients will have to wait for the roll-up document to
>   be updated, instead of computing the total by reading all of the
>   shards immediately after any update.
> - **Cost** - The cost of reading a
>   counter value increases linearly with the number of shards, because
>   the entire shards subcollection must be loaded.

You may also refer to this [guide](https://medium.com/evenbit/on-collision-course-with-cloud-firestore-7af26242bc2d) for more information.

Comment: Gotcha, I am currently using the counter and it works enough that it never misses a order count, but when 2 users are incrementing then reading the count at the same time , they see the same value and thus get the same order #.

You may have sent the wrong thread there at the end, I do not see any relevant content there!

Comment: Hi @douglasrcjames, I've updated my answer and added some guide. Thank you. :)